# Como remover propriedade herdada pelo componente?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, propriedade

Ao colocar um ícone de navegação lateral, percebi que um pedaço dele "vazou" para fora do esperado, o que fez ele se comportar  de forma visualmente estranha na animação. Coloquei um `background-color: red` para facilitar a visualização:

[image: área do ícone vazando para fora do desejado]

Mas, ao inspecionar o elemento da página, percebi que se eu removesse uma propriedade do CSS da tag `<i>` ele se comporta da forma desejada:

[image: ícone se comportando da forma desejada]
[image: propriedade <code>height</code> desmarcada]

mas se eu coloco `height: 0` no meu CSS a animação ocorre de outra forma estranha, além do elemento, aparentemente, não ter mais "fundo":

[image: ícone se comportando de forma estranha]

Como eu posso anular o comportamento de uma única propriedade herdado de tags e classes superiores no `CSS` sem perder os demais, que podem ser úteis?

**Estrutura do DOM:**

```
<body>
    <header class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="left col 2s">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <!-- conteúdo da página -->
</body>
```

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo, com código?

Comment: coloquei a estrutura do DOM, mas não sei o que mais poderia botar pra ajudar

Comment: basicamente, o `materialize-css` tem um CSS pronto para todos os elementos `<i>` situados de dentro de uma tag `<nav>`, mas eu quero remover uma das propriedades definidas e usar a padrão da página inteira

Comment: Talvez sobrescrever a classe CSS. Suponha que haja uma classe chamada `.a { height: 100px; }`, declare em um outro arquivo CSS a mesma classe alterando suas propriedades, ex.: `.a { heigth: unset }`. O importante é que sua alteração seja carregada depois da classe original.

Comment: @MarceloVismari era isso mesmo. Coloca em uma resposta pra eu poder fechar o tópico ;)

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira mete também o código daquele css na pergunta. Para poder criar um trecho de código executável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode sobrescrever as classes CSS para alterar as propriedades desejadas. Suponha que haja uma classe chamada `.a { height: 100px; }`, declare em um outro arquivo CSS a mesma classe alterando suas propriedades, ex.: `.a { heigth: unset }`. O importante é que sua alteração seja carregada depois da classe original.